# How do I print all lines of a file with duplicate values in a certain column

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

Given a file like this:

```
1,768,12,46576457,7898
1,123,435,134,146
2,345,6756856,12312,1311
5,234,567465,12341,1341
1,3245,4356345,2442,13
9,423,2342,121,463
9,989,342,121,1212
```

I would like to list all rows (in bash terminal) such that the value in column 1 appears at least twice (in column 1). The result should be

```
1,768,12,46576457,7898
1,123,435,134,146
1,3245,4356345,2442,13
9,423,2342,121,463
9,989,342,121,1212
```

Answer (score 13):

To try and avoid storing the whole file in memory, you could do:

```
awk -F , '
  !count[$1]++ {save[$1] = $0; next}
  count[$1] == 2 {
    print save[$1]
    delete save[$1]
  }
  {print}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl solution:

```
perl -F, -ane ' $h{ $F[0] } .= $_
                }{
                $h{$_} =~ tr/\n// >= 2 and print $h{$_} for keys %h
              ' < input-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on `-F`, i.e. comma, into the `@F` array.
- lines are stored in the `%h` hash keyed by the first field (`$F[0]`). They are concatenated together (`.=`).
- at the end of the file ("Eskimo greeting" `}{`), we loop over the keys and count the number of newlines (using the `tr` operator). If its at least 2, we print the stored lines.

You can feed the output to `| sort -n` if you want the first column to be numerically sorted.

*Attention:* if the last line didn't end in a newline, its group would report its size - 1. You can `chomp` each line and add the newlines yourself to fix it, or use array of arrays of lines instead of array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

With awk (GNU awk for multi-dimensional arrays)

```
gawk -F, '
    { line[NR] = $0; count[$1]++; found[$1][NR] = 1}
    END {
        for (id in count)
            if (count[id] > 1)
                for (nr in found[id]) 
                    print line[nr]
    }
' file
```

The order of the output may not be the same as the input file.

Comment: I believe that's GNU AWK 4. Earlier versions handle (fake) multi-dimensional arrays differently.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant (where `test.txt` is your input file):

```
FILE=test.txt ; for n in $(cat ${FILE} | awk -F"," '{count[$1]++} END {for (i in count) print i":"count[i]}'|grep -v ':1'|awk -F: '{print $1}');do grep ^${n} ${FILE} ;done
```

Comment: That's just about the ugliest thing I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

column_delimiter = sys.argv[1]
column = int(sys.argv[2]) - 1

records = defaultdict(list)
for l in sys.stdin:
    l = l.rstrip('\n')
    r = l.split(column_delimiter)
    records[r[column]].append(l)

for ll in records.values():
    if len(ll) > 1:
        print(*ll, sep='\n')
```

Usage:

```sh
python3 duplicate-columns.py COLUMN-DELIMITER COLUMN
```

Example:

```sh
python3 duplicate-columns.py ',' 1 < data.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure shell script variant (only relying on **sort**):

```
FILE=your.file
last_key=""
last_tail=""
first_match=yes
sort -t, -k1,1 $FILE |
while IFS=, read key tail
do
  if [[ $key = $last_key ]]
  then
    if [[ $first_match = yes ]] 
    then
      echo $last_key,$last_tail
      first_match=no
    fi
    echo $key,$tail
  else
    first_match=yes
  fi
  last_key=$key
  last_tail=$tail
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another pure bash script, built entirely with internal bash commands and operators. Associative arrays make the trickiest parts. This solution is very efficient, because the file is scanned just once and few data are stored in memory.

```
FILE=your.file
unset keys; declare -A keys
unset first_of; declare -A first_of
while IFS=, read key tail
do
  (( count = ++keys[$key] ))
  (( count==1 )) && { first_of[$key]="$tail"; continue; }
  (( count==2 )) && echo $key,${first_of[$key]}
  echo $key,$tail
done <$FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv -N count-similar -g 1 -o count then filter '$count>1' then cut -x -f count ./input.csv >./output.csv
```

you will have

```
1,768,12,46576457,7898
1,123,435,134,146
1,3245,4356345,2442,13
9,423,2342,121,463
9,989,342,121,1212
```

Some notes:

- `count-similar -g 1` to count grouping by field 1 values;
- `-o count`, to set the output count field;
- `filter '$count>1'`, to filter records where `count` field is greater than one;
- `then cut -x -f count`, to remove the `count` field

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(cat given | cut -d, -f1)
do
  linect=$(grep ^"${i}," given | wc -l)
  if [ ${linect} -gt 1 ]
  then
    grep ^"${i}," given >> result
  fi
done
sort result |uniq > desiredoutput
```

as long as the fields are delimited by comma and you are seeking duplicates in the column 1 and column 1 only, this should work.

Comment: can be written as `grep -f <(cut -d, -f1 file | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>1 {print "^"$2","}') file`

Comment: one of the many ways it can be written, is in my example. I just wanted to make it easier to understand.

Comment: understood. Just making it more efficient: one grep call versus 2n calls.

Comment: @glennjackman I like your solution. however, it appears to not work with huge files. I'm not sure if that's an issue with grep.