# awk, duplicate Values

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to write a script to return duplicate values based on a set of parameters if they repeat twice.  For example in my text file I have this setup:

```
SPPARK|6543|M1122|6543|Hendrick|Brian|1977/11/09||
SPPARK|1245|M3344|6543|Hendrick|Brian|1977/11/09||
```

Now if the Last Name, First Name, and DOB repeat I want it too return both those lines and continue on, I know **awk** can do this, but it doesn't seem to work right.

```
awk '!seen[$4,$5]++ > 1' DemoDATA.txt
```

Comment: show your current code

Comment: `man sort` (-u may be useful in some situations) and especially `man uniq` seems something you should look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '!seen[$4, $5]++ > 1' DemoDATA.txt
```

is almost correct, apart from the fact that the fields in the file are delimited by `|`, and that the fields you should look at for the last name and date of birth are fields 5, 6 and 7. You also don't have to compare with 1 (I can see why you do that, but the comparison would never be true).

Corrected:

```
awk -F '|' '!seen[$5, $6, $7]++' DemoDATA.txt
```

This will however only output the duplicates, not the original line. To do that, you would have to save the whole file in memory as you're parsing it...

... which is what the answers to "[How do I print all lines of a file with duplicate values in a certain column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255563/how-do-i-print-all-lines-of-a-file-with-duplicate-values-in-a-certain-column)" are doing (or not, if they are smart, which some of them are).

Answer (score 0):

As Kusalananda suggested, saving the whole file in memory:

```
awk -F'|' '
    {
        key = $5 FS $6 FS $7
        count[key]++
        data[key] = data[key] (count[key] == 1 ? "" : ORS) $0
    }
    END { for (key in count) if (count[key] > 1) print data[key] }
' DemoDATA.txt
```

or

```
perl -F'\|' -ane '
        $key = join "|", @F[4..6];
        push @{$data{$key}}, $_;
    } END {
        print @{$data{$_}} for grep {@{$data{$_}} > 1} keys %data;
' DemoDATA.txt
```